# Control of transistor as switch at power up and power down

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I need to replace a physical switch with a transistor. I have a 12V supply which is always on, and i have a 12V control signal.

I need some way of generating a short pulse on both the power up of the 12V control signal and the power down of the control signal. It must be a short pulse (to replicate a short button press <1s >500ms).

I looked at 555 monostable timer circuits but they need to see high-low-high. Where as I can provide only high-low and low-high.

Can anyone provide any hints on possible ICs or circuits to achieve this please?

Comment: Do you have a transistor in mind already? Or are you unsure on which to use?

Comment: @Reinderien i hadnt got that far yet, the more pressing concern was how to pulse it. Ill spec the transistor later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going into too much detail I would consider the exclusive or gate edge detector circuit: -

[image]

This can be scaled up in time by using much bigger values for the capacitor and resistor of course. See also [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270089/falling-and-rasing-edge-detector) for a rising/falling edge detector - it goes into more detail.

Comment: brilliant, thanks for this! if only i had thought to google edge detector, whicch is exactly what i was looking for.